# R - how to compare a list of characters with an online article

Tags: r

I have a list of vectors:

```
vector <- c("Retail","real consumption","jobs")
```

I want to compare the list of vectors with an online article:

```
https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html
```

I want to output how many matches there are for each characters. For examples, how many times "Retail" happen in the article, and how many times "real consumption" happen in the article, regardless of capitals.

The first step I took is download the website link using

```
article <- download.file("https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html",destfile="basename(url)",method="libcurl")
```

But I got error message:

```
cannot open URL 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file("https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html",  :
  URL 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html': status was 'Couldn't resolve host name'
```

New Edit:
I also tried below, but I'm not sure where does this go?

```
con <- url("https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html", "rb") 
article <- read_html(con)
```

Above is just an example, in my real example, I need to compare a list of vectors with many online articles. Can anyone show me a way to do it, is there any built-in package I could use? Thanks a lot ahead!

Comment: I'd probably `download.file` then `readLines`, `strsplit` it based on whitespace, likely `tolower` it for easier comparison, then use `%in%` and/or `table` or similar. Have you tried anything, vicky? Solve your problem with one file and one vector of words, then we can suggest how to apply your process to multiple files, multiple vectors.

Comment: `tidytext` and `quanteda` are both packages made for this sort of thing.

Comment: Hi vicky, I think this question is too broad. There are a lot of steps, including scraping the data, pre-processing it, tokenizing it, and the performing the analysis. If you get stuck on any of the steps, if you provide the code you've tried so far, I suspect many of us would be willing to help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I got error on first step - download.file. It's not a file but it's a website link, so I'm not sure about the syntax. I tried "download.file("https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html",destfile="basename(url)",method="libcurl")", error is "cannot open URL 'https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html'"

Comment: vicky, whether `download.file` or `readLines` or `xml2::read_html` or `rvest::html_session`, it really doesn't matter ... ultimately, the first step is to *get the data*.

Comment: Scratch that, I thought you were further along than you seem to be (and I mis-spoke earlier about `download.file`). You need to learn about scraping data, and `rvest` is a great tool to do that (likely the best tool for R). Once you have that, I second @ChuckP's comment about helpful packages that are made for textual analysis.

Comment: BTW, the `'Couldn't resolve host name'` is indeed a problem: it worked for me, so you have bigger problems: a computer that does not see host names correctly (esp yahoo.com. Also, your use of `destfile="basename(url)"` is wrong, perhaps you meant to define a variable `url <- "https://finance.yahoo.com/..."`, then remove the quotes, `destfile = basename(url)`.

Comment: I tried library(rvest)
article <- html("https://finance.yahoo.com/news/coroanvirus-covid-may-2020-retail-sales-171911895.html"), but I got error "Could not resolve host: finance.yahoo.com".